# MySQL: Can only login from command line or as root

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to solve this problem for the last 3h. I've just set up a MySQL server on my dedicated root server, running Ubuntu 14.04-minimal. I have no problem logging in as root anywhere - it works just fine on the command line, phpMyAdmin or a php-Script.

Because I did not want to use all my scripts as the root user, I created a new one using this command:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER ON *.*
'myUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword';
```

The user got successfully created and I can login with my password from the command line. However, it seems to be impossible to access MySQL with another user than root from something that is **not** the commandline.

At first I thought it might be the common host problem, where you have to use *both* `%` and `localhost` in the mysql.user database in order to access it from outside the console. But this did not work. I even added the two host entries that the root-user also has (`hostname`, `::1`), but I always get the typical `Error #1045 - Cannot Log in to MySQL server`. What I've also tried is to directly connect in my scripts (or phpMyAdmin) to either the server's IP-Address or 127.0.01 instead of localhost - without success.

So here is the current status:

- Login as `root` from the console: Works.
- Login as `root` from anything else: Works.
- Login as `myUser` from the console: Works.
- Login as `myUser` from anything else: **Doesn't work**.

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this issue?

Comment: Some special characters in the password passing not through PHP ? Just a guess...

Comment: There are special characters in the password, but phpMyAdmin should be able to escape them correctly, shouldn't it? Because I can't login there either.

Comment: Wow, I just tried it out and changed the password to an easy one without special characters - and it finally **works**! Still can't believe that phpMyAdmin doesn't pass the characters correctly to MySQL... Anyway, many thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it's the reply, (see comments). I put it here to mark the question answered.
Some special  characters in the password may not be forwarded correctly by php. Try with a regular password (ASCII 7 bit set, no control chars).

Comment: Again, many thanks for your help. I probably would have never guessed this on my own. So basically it is not possible to use a complex password on a MySQL user when logging in to phpMyAdmin is required?

Comment: Maybe something can be done in php configuration, but I'm not a php expert, so I can't tell. You should go to a php forum to get a full explanation. Have a nice time !